# next-auth/discord callbacks arent modifying data

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm using `next-auth/discord` however when using the `session` callback to set a user id to the session it does not set the property.

`[...nextauth].js`

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      ...
      session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        ...
      },
      callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user }) {
          session.user.id = user.id;
          return session;
        }
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

`/api/page.js`

```js
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  console.log(session);
}
```

This logs:

```json
{
  user: {
    name: ...,
    email: ...,
    image: ...
  },
  expires: ...
}
```

With no `user.id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, callbacks should have been in `NextAuth` object. Also callbacks shouldve been:

```js
async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id
      return session
    }
```